# How can I pass decimal values from view to controller using Vue.js?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

Im trying to pass values from view to controller using Vue.js, but Im getting a problem with decimal values only. When I input decimal values and post it to controller, it arrives NULL.

Note: Only for decimal values, to Integer or String values it's ok.

Here is my code:

```js
salvarProdutos: function () {
            load();
            this.$http.post(urlInit + '/Quotation/updateInfoComercial/', {
                RefCotacao: this.refCotacao,
                //InformaçoesComerciais//
                Qtd: this.quantidade,
                UnidadeMedida: this.unidadeMedida,
                ValorUnitario: this.valorUnitarioProduto,
                LoteMinimo: this.loteMinimo,
                PrazoEntrega: this.prazoEntrega,
                PorcentagemMaxVariacao: this.porcentagemVariacao
                //--------------------------//
            }).then((response) => {
                unload();
                if (response.data.worked) {
                    alert("Dados salvos com sucesso!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Erro - Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="porcentagemVariacao">
                                        Porcentagem máxima de variação
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="number" min="1" step="0.1" class="form-control" id="porcentagemVariacao" v-model="porcentagemVariacao" required>
                                        <span class="material-input"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult updateInfoComercial(string refCotacao, InformacoesComerciais infoCF, string form)
    {
        var partNumber = infoCF.PartNumber;
        var porcentagem = infoCF.PorcentagemMaxVariacao;

        var message = "";

        message = "OK";
        return Json(new { message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public partial class InformacoesComerciais
{
    public InformacoesComerciais() { }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    //public int ID { get; set; }

    public decimal? Qtd { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string UnidadeMedida { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string RefCotacao { get; set; }

    public decimal? ValorUnitario { get; set; }

    public decimal? LoteMinimo { get; set; }

    public decimal? PorcentagemMaxVariacao { get; set; }

    //[Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public string PrazoEntrega { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: can you provide an example value that fails?

Comment: Example: I need to input 2.1 or 2,1 in the field "porcentagemVariacao" and when I post it, it arrive NULL at controler.

Comment: If I input 2, it works.

Comment: Please post what your `InformacoesComerciais` model looks like

Comment: @GregH posted :)

Comment: Do you have the same issue with your other decimal properties?

Comment: Yes, any decimal values.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue: [one](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3259/passing-decimals-to-action-methods-in-mvc), [two](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/). And the proposed solution is to custom bind decimals

Answer (score 0):

I change the `<globalization>` tag in Web.config and works:

Before:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

After:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Thanks.